# Increment or create a numeric value in an array

Tags: php

I want to create or increment a value for a key in an array. So for example if I have a key 'money' I can increment it in the array by a set value, or create it if it doesn't exist yet. Currently I'm doing this which seems a long way of going about it.

```
if(array_key_exists("money", $account_array)) {
    $account_array["money"] = $account_array["money"] + $increase;
}
else {
    $account_array["money"] = $increase;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!isset($account_array['money'])) {
    $account_array['money'] = 0;
}

$account_array["money"] += $increase;
```

- use `isset()` if you can be sure that the array does either contain a non-null value or that it does not contain key at all.
- use `a += b` which would be equivalent to `a = a + b`

Comment: Is there any advantage of isset over array_key_exists apart from it's shorter?

Comment: @justinhj They have a major difference! *array_key_exists()* checks whether a key exists whose value mustn't be null.

Comment: There is a small mistake in the answer near 'isset[', it should be round bracket, like 'isset('.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
    array_key_exists("money", $account_array) ? $account_array["money"] += $increase : $account_array["money"] = $increase;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a ternary statement and *compress* it to a single line, but this compromises readability:

```
$account_array["money"] = (array_key_exists("money", $account_array)) ? 
$account_array["money"] + $increase : $increase;
```

[**See it live!**](http://3v4l.org/OSH0V)

Answer (score 0):

you could shorten the synatx a bit, but basically your method is correct

```
array_key_exists('money', $account_array) 
    ? $account_array["money"] += $increase 
    : $account_array["money"] = $increase;
```